# How come the determinant of a matrix have to be 0 to find the eigenvalue and vector?

Tags: matrices

I need help understanding why if the determinant of a matrix is 0 then there exists a matrix such that multiplying it by a vector get 0 and how this relates to eigenvectors and eigenvalues. For example, why do you find the determinant, all I know is that if the determinant is 0, then there is no inverse. So I am very confused and dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose determinant of a square matrix $A$ is zero. In that case the characteristic equation $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$ clearly has the root $\lambda=0$. It follows that $0$ is an eigen value of $A$. The converse is similar. Hence we may conclude that:

*A square matrix has $0$ as an eigen value if and only if its determinant is zero.*